# Dirichlet fractional Laplacian and zero boundary conditions

Tags: real-analysis, differential-equations, unbounded-operators, fractional-calculus

Does there exists a non-zero function $$f\in C_0([0,1]):=\{f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R:\ f\text{ is continuous and } f(0)=f(1)=0\},$$ such that $(-\Delta)^{\frac\alpha 2}f\in C_0([0,1]) $, where $(-\Delta)^{\frac\alpha 2}$ is the Dirichlet fractional Laplacian defined by
$$
(-\Delta)^{\frac\alpha 2}f(x):=\int_0^1(f(x)-f(y))\frac{dy}{|x-y|^{1+\alpha}}+f(x)\int_{\mathbb R\backslash (0,1)}\frac{dy}{|x-y|^{1+\alpha}},\ \ x\in(0,1),
$$
and $(-\Delta)^{\frac\alpha 2}f(0):=\lim_{x\to 0^+}(-\Delta)^{\frac\alpha 2}f(x)$, $(-\Delta)^{\frac\alpha 2}f(1):=\lim_{x\to 1^-}(-\Delta)^{\frac\alpha 2}f(x)$, where $\alpha \in(0,2)$ (principal value definition of the first integral).

My question is motivated by the last part of [Theorem 2.7](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.06421.pdf), as the existence of the function I am looking for would allow me to apply that theorem.

Note that the above definition of $(-\Delta)^{\frac \alpha 2}$  agrees with the definition of  the restricted fractional Laplacian in [formula (3.1) here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.07871.pdf), which differs from definition of the spectral fractional Laplacian in [formula (3.4) here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.07871.pdf).

(I asked the same question on Math.SE but it received low attention. I then though it might be better to post it here, let me know if it's not ok)

Comment: [Link to Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2674904/8157)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are many functions with this property. In fact, these functions are dense in $C_0([0,1])$.

---

For every $g \in C_0([0,1])$ there is a unique $f \in C_0([0,1])$ such that $(-\Delta)^{\alpha/2} f(x) = g(x)$ for $x \in [0,1]$. This $f$ is given more-or-less explicitly: $$f(x) = \int_0^1 G_{(0,1)}(x, y) g(y) dy,$$ where $G_{(0,1)}(x,y)$ is the Green function for $(-\Delta)^{\alpha/2}$ in $(0, 1)$: $$
 G_{(0,1)}(x,y) = \frac{|x - y|^{\alpha - 1}}{2^\alpha (\Gamma(\alpha/2))^2} \int_0^{R(x,y)} \frac{s^{\alpha/2 - 1}}{\sqrt{1 + s}} \, ds
$$
with $$ R(x,y) = \frac{4 x (1 - x) y (1 - y)}{|x - y|^2} \, .$$

---

*(Edited).*
In fact, the class of functions $f$ defined above constitute the domain of $(-\Delta)^{\alpha/2}$ on $(0, 1)$, with zero exterior condition, and therefore it is dense in $C_0([0,1])$. A rigorous proof of this claim is somewhat complicated, though.

The fractional Laplacian $-(-\Delta)^{\alpha/2}$ is the Feller generator of (the transition semigroup of) the symmetric $\alpha$-stable Lévy process $X_t$. Let $D = (0, 1)$ and let $X_t^D$ be the process $X_t$ killed when it first exits $D$. Since every boundary point of $D$ is regular, $X_t^D$ is a Feller process, and hence its Feller generator is a densely defined operator on $C_0(D)$. Denote this Feller generator by $L$.

By the general theory of strongly continuous semigroups, $f$ is in the domain of $L$ if and only if $f(x) = \int_D G_D(x, y) g(y) dy$ for some $g \in C_0(D)$, and in this case $g = -L f$. What remains to be proved is that if $f$ belongs to the domain of $L$, then $L f(x) = -(-\Delta)^{\alpha/2} f(x)$.

It was proved by Dynkin (in his brilliant book [*Markov processes*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-662-00031-1)) that $f \in C_0(D)$ is in the domain of $L$ if and only if the limit in
$$
 \tilde{L} f(x) = \lim_{r \to 0^+} \frac{\mathbb{E}^x f(X(\tau_{B(x, r)})) - f(x)}{\mathbb{E}^x \tau_{B(x, r)}}
$$
exists for every $x \in D$ and it defines a function $\tilde{L} f$ in $C_0(D)$; in this case $\tilde{L} f(x) = L f(x)$ for all $x \in D$. (The operator $\tilde{L}$ is the *Dynkin characteristic operator*).

Now the important fact is that the definition of $\tilde{L} f(x)$ does not depend on $D$! (It does not matter whether we use the killed process $X_t^D$ or the free process $X_t$ in the definition, as long as $f = 0$ in the complement of $D$).

Furthermore, convergence in the definition of $\tilde{L} f(x)$ implies convergence to the same limit in the definition of $-(-\Delta)^{\alpha/2} f(x)$ as a singular integral (for any fixed point $x$). This phenomenon seems to be specific to the fractional Laplacian, and it appears that it has been first observed [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/fca-2017-0002).

---

Final remark: Regarding the converse claim: "if $f \in C_0(D)$, $(-\Delta)^{\alpha/2} f(x)$ is well-defined as a singular integral for each $x \in D$ and it defines a $C_0(D)$ function", I believe it is not stated explicitly in the literature unless $D$ is full space.

Comment: I am indeed interested in the pointwise equality of the generator of the killed process with the fractional Laplacian applied to the function extended to zero outside of $(0,1)$. Are there such functions? Is $(-\Delta)^{\frac \alpha 2}$ in your first line the generator? (sorry but I'm not sure you answered this part)

Comment: @Ton: I expanded my answer, please see if it addresses your questions now.

Comment: Sorry, but is the following a counter-example? Let $f$ be smooth and positive inside its compact support in $(0,1)$. Then $(-\Delta)^{\frac \alpha 2}f(0)\neq 0=- L_{(0,1)}f(0)$,where $(L_{(0,1)},Dom(L_{(0,1)}))$ is the generator of the killed-$\alpha$-stable process (working on $C_0([0,1])$) and $f\in Dom(L_{(0,1)})$.  To conclude note that zero-extension of $f$ belongs the domain of the $\alpha$-stable process and its the generator agrees with $-(-\Delta)^{\frac \alpha 2}$ on $f$.

Comment: Also, I do not see how the characteristic operator $\tilde Lf$ can equal $-(-\Delta)^{\frac \alpha 2}f$ as values of $f$ outside any ball are ignored in the limiting definition ($\tilde Lf(x)=\tilde L g(x)$ for any $f,g$ such that $f=g$ a neighborhood of $x$, no?).

Comment: Actually, looking at Theorem 2.3 in arxiv.org/pdf/1604.06421.pdf does it follow that f∉Dom(L(0,1))? (where f is the f defined in the comment of mine about the counter example.). Also your Green function $G_{(0,1)}$ does not seem to allow for $f$ to be smooth.

Comment: @Ton: (1) No, this is not a counter-example: not all $C_c^\infty(D)$ functions are in the domain of the Feller generator $L$ of $X_t^D$ unless $D$ is full-space. You already pointed this in your last comment. (2) No, the expectation $\mathbb{E}^x f(X(\tau_{B(x,r)}))$ essentially depends on the values of $f$ everywhere, not just on the boundary. (3) I am afraid I did not understand the last part of your comment: the integral $\int_D G_D(x,y) g(y) dy$ can well be smooth.

Comment: (2) Really sorry, I misread the formula. (3) Forget that comment please. Need to think about the topic for a bit. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please point out where in https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/fca.2017.20.issue-1/fca-2017-0002/fca-2017-0002.xml it's proven that $\tilde Lf=-(-\Delta)^{\frac \alpha 2}f$ ? (struggling to find it)

Comment: @Ton: Lemmas 3.3 and 3.4 give pointwise results, Lemma 4.2 gives the norm analogue.